# Is os.path.basename meant for file system files?

Tags: python, os.path

In Windows, `os.path.basename('D:\\abc\def.txt')` returns `abc\def.txt`, whereas `os.path.basename('/abc/def.txt')` returns `def.txt`.

Shouldn't the first also return `def.txt`?

Comment: Not when `\d` is an escape sequence. I think you simplified out your problem; does `def` really start with `d` or perhaps with `r`, `t` or `n`?

Answer (score 2):

You have an *escape code* in your filename, not a `\` directory separator. You must've simplified your problem by using `def` for the filename, but had you actually tested with that simplified filename you'd have noticed that the slash would be doubled:

```
>>> 'D:\\abc\def.txt'
'D:\\abc\\def.txt'
```

Note that the `\d` in the string literal became a `\\` escaped backslash in the Python representation of the value. That's because there is no valid `\d` escape sequence. On a Windows system the `os.path.basename()` call works as expected for that path:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.basename('D:\\abc\\def.txt')
'def.txt'
```

In your case, however, you created an escape sequence, either `\n`, `\r` or `\t`, because you either forgot to double the backslash or you forgot to use a raw string. You do *not* have a `\` character in that part of the filename, so there is nothing to split on at that location.

Use a `r'...'` raw string to prevent single backslashes from forming escape sequences, or double your backslashes in all locations, or use *forward* slashes (Windows accepts either).

Comment: Thanks.  It was a typo in my tests.  Should be `'D:\\abc\\def.txt'`.

Comment: Exactly, you didn't escape the backslash, which is hat I said.